# How to get hour from subtract date and time in mysql?

Tags: datetime, mysql

How to get hour from subtract date and time in mysql?

```
2010-12-04 17:07:14 and 2010-05-30 17:07:19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you want the # of hours when subtracting the two dates. If that's the case I found the below here: http://www.dbforums.com/mysql/1637603-datediff-hours.html

> You can convert both times to seconds
>   using unix_timestamp. Then subtract
>   one from other to get number of
>   seconds between both times. Then
>   divide by 3600 to get the number of
>   hours

```
 select ( unix_timestamp( "2010-12-04 17:07:14" ) - 
     unix_timestamp("2010-05-30 17:07:19" ) ) / 3600
```

***Note:** This only works for dates after 1970